# VideoJS programmatic play only works with setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, next.js, settimeout, video.js

Basically when I call player.play() alone the video does not play, but when I wrap it in setTimeout (even with 1ms) the video plays.

My app is built in React with NextJS.

Here is how the code looks:

```
const [currentVideoElement, setCurrentVideoElement] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!currentVideoElement) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const currentVideoPlayer = videojs(currentVideoElement, {
    autoplay: true,
    controls: false,
    loop: true,
    preload: 'auto',
  });

  currentVideoPlayer.ready(() => {
    // Should be just: currentVideoPlayer.play();
    setTimeout(() => currentVideoPlayer.play(), 1);

    currentVideoPlayer.muted(
      isCurrentVideoMuted || !isCurrentVideoFullScreen
    );
  });

  return () => {
    currentVideoPlayer.pause();
    currentVideoPlayer.currentTime(0);
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [currentVideoElement]);
```

And the video element is as follows:

```
<video
  className="video-js vjs-custom h-full object-cover"
  playsInline
  muted
  ref={setCurrentVideoElement}
>
  <source src={url} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

For now this works, but would love to understand why this is happening!

Comment: I found similar effects in react native. I think there's something in the context of the hook that changes the scope of the function that's exciting in a way that screws up certain operations and setting the timeout effectively bumps you into a future JS loop and exits that constraint. I have used setImmediate to do this too. But none of this explains WHY really so I'm not going to write this as an answer so much as a way to share and tune in if someone else can elaborate better.

Comment: Thanks @Atmas! Good to at least know I am not alone!